# How does LayoutInflater work?

Tags: java, android, layout, view, layout-inflater

I am new to Android development, and I am curious about the phrase "Inflate a View", which is being thrown around in the Android development community.

I know it has to do with calling the Inflate method of the `LayoutInflater` class but I'm still yet to grasp the concept behind it. Does this basically mean returning a view by passing its ID just like JavaScript's `document.getElementById()` sort of thing or is there more to it? Any form of enlightenment will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It basically is the term used for instantiating an xml `Layout` file into an object to be used in the java code. You can do this by calling `setContentView(R.layout.file name minus xml extension)` or by using `LayoutInflater`. Only after inflating can you call its child `Views`. This is important to know because I have seen many questions on SO in which people have an app that crashes and it turns out that they are trying to reference a `view` like

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.someID);
```

and they haven't called `setContentView()` to obtain the `Layout` which holds that `EditText` which results in a `NPE` since the `EditText` doesn't actually exist until the `Layout` is `inflated`.

I'm sure you have seen the docs on it but [Here they are anyway](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)

Comment: your answers are well structured. +1

Answer (score 0):

While the specifics are surely more complicated than what I'm going to say, I think the easiest way to think of inflating views is as the process of going from the xml layout file to the actual `View` objects.  The inflation methods, which are peppered around a number of different classes, typically all take an `id` argument which you would set as `R.layout.xxx`.